# Can't use .env file in vue js while running cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use an .env file for local variables but when I try and console them, it comes up as undefined.

Below is my .env file (which is at the root of my project)

```
VUE_APP_STRAPI_HOST=http://localhost:1337/
```

And I'm using the following when trying to console log this:

```
console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_STRAPI_HOST)
```

Here is what I'm running in the command line again:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot
```

I'm thinking it's something to do with the cross-env maybe?

Comment: `.env` is not related to environment variables.

Comment: Looks like you're using raw Webpack instead of the Vue CLI, or this would have worked out of the box.  You're missing out on other features by doing this too

Comment: yeah I'm not using vue-cli which would have made my life much easier. Since I already built the entire thing with webpack, I'm going to try and see it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SHORT**:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

**TL;DR**:

The fact that you created `.env` file has nothing to do with environment variables. In bash (or any other sh system) you need either

- use command `export VUE_APP_STRAPI_HOST=http://localhost:1337/`; and then run your process
- either use `VUE_APP_STRAPI_HOST=http://localhost:1337/ node webpack-dev-server --open --hot` .

Simply just creating a `.env` file (as well as file with any other name) won't make variables in it magically exported to env variables to your process. The same applies to `cross-env`, since I don't see any documentation in this package that make it do it.

What you probably want is [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv):

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

But don't let the magic mislead you. This command just overrides global variable `process.env` with your config.

What you can also do is to read `.env` file and export everything in it to environment variables with any shell script like this one:

```
source_it() {
  while read -r line; do
    if [[ -n "$line" ]] && [[ $line != \#* ]]; then
      export "$line"
    fi
  done < $1
}
source_it .env
```

And then just run your process as you did before:

```
node ./node_modules/.bin/cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot
```

P.S.

Another thing that if you're trying to see `console.log` from your browser, it also has nothing to do with the node process your webpack-dev-server is running on. In order to make your `process.env` variable global to your browser you may use something like [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/)

Comment: When I install dotenv, I get the following message: ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Andre\Documents\Sage-Projects\Fresh-Beauty\fresh-beauty-front-end\node_modules\dotenv\lib --- I tried install fs to the project and that didn't work

Comment: Where do you put it? You need to put it into a process that has access to env variables. Not in your frontend files. Put this into webpack.config and add new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['VUE_APP_STRAPI_HOST']); https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/

Comment: took a break from this and just came back to it today, thank you so much! this was the solution for me. I'll answer my question to post my full solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @deathangel908, I came up with this solution:

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
  new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
    STRAPI_HOST: 'foobar'
  })
])
```

The downside of using webpack Environmentplugin is you can't use .env environment files like .env.development. Webpack has a plugin but in my project it kept throwing an error that I couldn't figure out how to fix